# Word count program not working. Code sample From the Book The C-programming Language Ritchie & Kernighan

Tags: c, wc

This is the code sample for the word counting program. But it's not working. When we execute it, after entering words it is supposed to display the results, but it is not producing anything.Anything missing in this code ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define IN  1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* counts lines, words, and characters in input */

 main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
        ++nc;
        if( c == '\n' )
            ++nl;
        if( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' )
            state = OUT;
        else if( state == OUT ){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }

    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Comment: `But it's not working`..please elaborate.

Comment: You are not new around here, are you? Just in case, you've missed, let me humbly point you once again to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine. You have to ask yourself how to break the while loop as it continuously reading input i.e. how to send `EOF` to your program.

On *nix systems, you do <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> and on Windows you do <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> to generate EOF.

Also: use one of standard signature for `main()` such as`int main(void)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine now. I have used main() since that was the code in that book.

Comment: It's totally okay using `main()` You can call it as `int main(float a)` if you like.

Comment: @malina: No it isn't. `main()` goes back to the days were a missing return type for a function defaulted to `int`, which is no longer a guarantee. The standard also specifies there two (and only two) valid definitions of `main`: `int main ( void )` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (C99: 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

Comment: The return type has nothing to do with the arguments passed to int. Also even if it comes to using main, using `float` instead of `int` doesn't violate anything even with the full level of complaints.

Comment: @Malina: It does, check the standard: _"The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters: `int main (void)` or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent; 10) or in some other implementation-defined manner."_

Comment: _"Equivalent"_ is specified in a footnote as follows: _"Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as
char ** argv, and so on."_. Any other `main` definition (ie returning a float for some reason) is _implementation defined_, and therefore non-standard and non-portable

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That doesn't change the thing. Even though it is not mentioned by standards, it doesn't mean it is "invalid". It will still run the program correctly, arguments are there only to interact with the cl. Your program wouldn't look correct if called as `main(float argc)` but standards < knowing exactly how main entry works.

Comment: @Malina: Check the last comment: _"implementation defined"_ means no guarantees that your code can be compiled correctly by another standard-compliant compiler. According to the standard, a compiler _may_ accept `float main (struct some_struct *foo)`, but that doesn't make it standard, and sure as hell doesn't make your code portable

Comment: Well yes. gcc describes a number of constraint-optimizations. Would make me a terrible programmer if I relied on this. Just pointed out that this is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my version
This program in K&R counts other char as well
but my version only count characters which are only alphabets.
and yeah you have to press Ctrl+d to send EOF signal to this program to execute printf statement after while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c = 0;    // input variable
    int lc = 0;   // line count
    int wc = 0;   // word count
    int cc = 0;   // char count
    int state = 0;// check space after word
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            ++lc;
        }
        if((c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') && state == 1){
            ++wc;
            state = 0;
        }
        else if((c >= 'A' || c>= 'a') && (c <='Z' || c <= 'z'){
        //this is to count only character between A or a and Z or z
            ++cc;
            state = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("lc = %d\twc = %d\tcc = %d\n",lc,wc,cc);
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**